# Error while opening WAS8.5.5 console and clicking on any values inside

Tags: websphere

I am getting error "Line: 318 Error: 'XULElement' is undefined" while clicking any button on WAS admin console. Server and profile are up and running. what should I do now?

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you share info about your system? Knowing which OS you use can provide help

Comment: I am using Windows 7 professional OS

Comment: Try different browsers, like FireFox to see if it is repeatable across different browsers.

Comment: Thanks Gas, it worked in other browsers when i open it outside from RAD.